# total number of reviews

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am getting 5 reviews while calling google place API, but I need more than 5 reviews and the value of total number of reviews available on google plus business profile. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

**Mar 14, 2019 Update**

After five years, Google has *finally* added support to the Maps JavaScript API to get the total number of reviews with the [3.35](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases#335) update.

The `user_ratings_total` property can be used to get the total number of reviews. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceResult.user_ratings_total) for more information.

<strike>Unfortunately, the API will only return a maximum of five reviews and there's currently no way to get the total number of reviews.</strike>

If you vote for the [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5650&q=apitype%3DPlacesAPI&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&start=100) to return the total number of reviews, it will help increase the chances of Google adding it.

Comment: It looks like Google finally added `user_ratings_total` field for total number of reviews. It also mentioned in release notes: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases#335